# Dart - problem with multi-dimensional lists

Tags: list, dart

I am programming in Dart and I need a multi-dimensional array to be filled with some data. But when I tried to run it, data at previous indexes were overwritten.

Here is my code:

```dart
List<List<String>> list = List.filled(4, List.filled(4, ""));
String toFill = "abcdefghijklmnop";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      list[i][j] = toFill[i * 4 + j];
    }
}

print(list);
```

I expected output of `print()` function to be

```
[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l], [m, n, o, p]]
```

but when I run it, it printed

```
[[m, n, o, p], [m, n, o, p], [m, n, o, p], [m, n, o, p]]
```

I don't know, why the last part is duplicating over to previous values.

I'd be glad for any help.

Thanks

Comment: This is explained by the documentation for the [`List.filled`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) constructor. Each element is initialized to a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this use List.generate which makes a new list from an iterable.

```
List<List<String>> list = List.generate(4, (int index) => List.generate(4, (int index) => ""));
```

Which gives me

```
> [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l], [m, n, o, p]]
```

This seems a little verbose, so there may be a shortcut to do the same thing.

**Edit**: Since you don't care about the `index` variable, you can shorten it somewhat but ignoring it:

```
List<List<String>> list = List.generate(4, (_) => List.generate(4, (_) => ""));
```

Comment: Or `var list = [for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) [for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) toFill[i * 4 + j]]]` if you prefer literals.

Answer (score 0):

You could also combine the creating and filling the list:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  String toFill = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  List<List<String>> list = List.generate(
    (toFill.length/4).ceil(),
    (i) => toFill.substring(i*4, min(toFill.length, (i+1)*4)).split(''),
  );
  print(list);
}
```

```
[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l], [m, n, o, p], [q, r, s, t], [u, v, w, x], [y, z]]
```

Which, if your string is always 16 characters long, can be simplified to:

```dart
void main() {
  String toFill = "abcdefghijklmnop";
  List<List<String>> list = List.generate(
    4,
    (i) => toFill.substring(i*4, (i+1)*4).split(''),
  );
  print(list);
}
```